# How WAL file LSN reflect their position in the abstract WAL sequence

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL How WAL file LSN reflect their position in the abstract WAL sequence
LSN seems very weird as they reflect in hexadecimal format, unlikely Oracle which clearly denotes the position of redo log files
Which all files I need to backup or save by checking the filename seems difficult in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple.

A base backup will generate a `backup_label` file that contains the WAL segment containing the checkpoint that starts the backup.

You need that WAL segment and all following ones until the point to which you want to recover. The order of the WAL segments is the hexadecimal number of the file name.

You can use the function `pg_walfile_name` to get the WAL segment that contains a certain LSN, but here is an explanation:

- a WAL file name is of the form `TTTTTTTTXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYY`, where

  - the first 8 hexadecimal digits of the WAL file name are the *time line* of the database
  - the next 8 hexadecimal digits of the WAL file form a number `X`
  - the final 8 hexadecimal digits of the WAL file form a number `Y`
- a LSN is of the form `XXX/YYZZZZZZ`, where

  - the hexadecimal number before the slash are the same `X` as above (without leading zeros)
  - if the number after the slash has less than 8 hexadecimal digits, add leading zeros
  - the first two hexadecimal digits after the slash are the same `Y` as above
  - the final 6 hexadecimal digits are the offset within that WAL segment.

This assumes that you stick with the default WAL segment size of 16MB.

Comment: even i use pg_walfile_name the return value is weird

Comment: "Weird" is not a technical category. Are you just venting your esthetical judgement or do you have a technical problem? There wasn't really a question in your question...

Comment: It is not techical category, but what does the WAL filenames names, filenames are not in sequence of the LSN. If I have a bunch of WAL files how to identify which one was generate before which file, what is the sequence, in case i do not have access to database .  How does this filenames corresponds to each LSN

Comment: @ArnavS: if you don't have a running Postgres instance, you can use [pg_waldump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgwaldump.html) to see the LSNs included in a WAL segment.

Comment: I have extended the answer to make the connection clear.

Comment: LSN also is not a number it is alpanumeric, how to identify the series

Comment: It is numeric in the hexadecimal number system. If you have dealings with computers regularly, a passing familiarity with hexadecimal numbers will be helpful. But for this purpose, alphabetic ordering (like `ls` provides by default) will suffice.